# styling a drop down menu with css3

Tags: css

The following code looks nice and it almost works

```
select{
   width:218px;
   background-color: #000;
   border:none;
   outline: none;
   color:#333; 
   -webkit-appearance:none;
   height:24px;
   border-radius: 0;
   -webkit-border-top-left-radius: 5px;
   -webkit-border-bottom-left-radius: 5px;
   border-top-left-radius: 5px;
   border-bottom-left-radius: 5px;
}

.selcet_wrapper{
   background:url(../image/contact_arrow.png) no-repeat 96% 0;
   background-size: 21px 24px;
   overflow: hidden;
   -webkit-border-top-right-radius: 5px;
   -webkit-border-bottom-right-radius: 5px;
   border-top-right-radius: 5px;
   border-bottom-right-radius: 5px;
   width:21px;
   height:24px;
```

}

```
<div class="selcet_wrapper">
  <select name="how" id="how">
  <option selected="selected" value="audi">What is your enquiry regarding?</option>
  <option value="volvo">one</option>
  <option value="saab">two</option>
  <option value="vw">three</option>
  </select>
</div>
```

When I click on the bg image the drop down doesn't show and I know that is because it is not included within the select element, is there a way around for this?

Comment: I've initialized a fiddle with your code but I don't understand your problem. Please look at this and improve your question : http://jsfiddle.net/eQv6t/

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/eQv6t/1/ the issue is that if you click on the red part the drop down doesn't show and I need the drop down to be styled in a specific way....

Comment: Why don't you specify a width of 100% on the select box ?